# How to change where git stores its credentials?

Tags: git, github, windows-10

When I execute:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

I get:

```
error: could not lock config file X://.gitconfig: Permission denied
```

That's because the corporate policy has set the HOMEDRIVE environment variable to be X:, which doesn't exist.  I can't override this.

How can I tell git to stores its credentials locally somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a newer version of git, point the environment variable `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to a directory that will then hold a subdirectory for git configuration, as explained by the [FILES section of the `git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES) documentation.

> `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`
>
> Second user-specific configuration file. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set or empty, `$HOME/.config/git/config` will be used. Any single-valued variable set in this file will be overwritten by whatever is in `~/.gitconfig.` It is a good idea not to create this file if you sometimes use older versions of Git, as support for this file was added fairly recently.

Comment: Creating XDG_CONFIG_HOME didn't do anything, but it did lead me towards a solution.  Looks like on Windows git uses HOME environment variable.  Changing that from X: to my profile dir did the trick.